# Why 親切 is not usually used when referring to one’s own family or close friends?

Tags: usage

"Like 優しい, the na-adjective 親切(しんせつ) means “kind,” and it is used to evaluate someone who does something kind for a person in trouble or is considerate to others. However, 親切 is used to describe the character of someone based on his/her action, and is not usually used when referring to one’s own family or close friends. " [source](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2016/05/16/language/two-kind-complementary-compliments-yasashii-shinsetsu/#.Wu16NnOxU0M)

Why  親切 is incompatible with "describing the character of someone based on his/her action" when referring to one’s own family or close friends ?

Comment: Because 親切 means/implies "to be helpful/hospitable to *others/他人* ", maybe?

Comment: @Chocolate For you this sentence "彼が親切な人だと思う。" means that he is kind to "others" (others= not family and not close friends) without telling clearly that he is also kind with family and close friends ?

Comment: Yeah.. when I heard 彼は親切な人だと思う I'd just think the person is nice/helpful to 他人... Unlike 優しい, 親切な sounds pretty distant. If I heard あの人は優しいと思う I'd think s/he is nice to anyone, like family, friends, strangers, or maybe animals too...